# Trying to use rundll32 printui.dll, PrintUIEntry to set up a printer, getting an error

Tags: command-line, printer

So I'm using the following line to set up a printer:

```
C:\>rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "Saturn" /f w:\printers\toshibae351
1\eng\est_c2.inf /m "TOSHIBA e-STUDIO Color PS3"
```

However I am getting the error "The arguments are invalid"

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here? I read on a separate place that I have to use the exact name in the inf file for the printer, but I believe I am doing that.

What else might it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in the same place and then accidentally stumbled across the /K (note that's upper-case) that fixed this for me on a win7x64 ultimate machine.

[Reference for the printui.dll stuff here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Hope it helps.

Carl